# Selecting and renaming columns at the same time

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

I looked around but could not find the solution for this. In `R's dplyr` we can select and rename column in one line of code.

```
select(Com=Commander,Sco=Score)
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in pandas but could not find feasible solution for it yet!

Let's say we have this sample data

```
# Create an example dataframe
data = {'Commander': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'Date': ['2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08'], 
        'Score': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])
df


           Commander          Date  Score
Cochice        Jason  2012, 02, 08      4
Pima           Molly  2012, 02, 08     24
Santa Cruz      Tina  2012, 02, 08     31
Maricopa        Jake  2012, 02, 08      2
Yuma             Amy  2012, 02, 08      3
```

and want to select and rename Commander and Score columns like this

```
df[['Com'=='Commander','Sco'=='Score']]
```

> ValueError: Item wrong length 2 instead of 5.

How can I do that ?

Comment: please, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917660/how-can-i-select-and-rename-a-long-list-of-columns-from-a-data-frame-in-r

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A bit late, and maybe you've already figured this out, but I had the same problem and the answers here got me most of the way to the solution I used.

The shortest answer to "how to add a range to select" is to pass the list of selected columns to the resultant dataframe of your rename operation:

```
df.rename(columns = {"Commander": "Com", "Score": "Sco"})[['Com', 'Sco']]

              Com  Sco
Cochice     Jason    4
Pima        Molly   24
Santa Cruz   Tina   31
Maricopa     Jake    2
Yuma          Amy    3
```

But it's a little tedious to rewrite the column names, right? So you can initialize the rename with a dictionary:

```
selector_d = {'Commander': 'Com', 'Score': 'Sco'}
```

and pass that to the rename *and* select operations:

```
df.rename(columns=selector_d)[[*selector_d.values()]]
              Com  Sco
Cochice     Jason    4
Pima        Molly   24
Santa Cruz   Tina   31
Maricopa     Jake    2
Yuma          Amy    3
```

My scenario was close to this - I had columns that I did not want to rename, but I did want to select them. This can be done by including the columns in the rename/select dictionary, but using the same name.

Here's the whole process with another column added:

```
data = {
    'Commander': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
    'Date': ['2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08',
             '2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08'],
    'Score': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
    'Team': ['Green', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Yellow'],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])
df

           Commander          Date  Score    Team
Cochice        Jason  2012, 02, 08      4   Green
Pima           Molly  2012, 02, 08     24  Yellow
Santa Cruz      Tina  2012, 02, 08     31   Green
Maricopa        Jake  2012, 02, 08      2  Yellow
Yuma             Amy  2012, 02, 08      3  Yellow

selector_d = {'Team': 'Team', 'Commander': 'Com', 'Score': 'Sco'}

df.rename(columns=selector_d)[[*selector_d.values()]]

              Team    Com  Sco
Cochice      Green  Jason    4
Pima        Yellow  Molly   24
Santa Cruz   Green   Tina   31
Maricopa    Yellow   Jake    2
Yuma        Yellow    Amy    3
```

As you can see, this also allows reordering of the columns in the final dataframe.

### Edited on 2021-08-28, per comment by @Hedge92

Actually, you don't need the double brackets to select the columns from `selector_d.values()`, as seen here:

```
df.rename(columns=selector_d)[[*selector_d.values()]].equals(
    df.rename(columns=selector_d)[selector_d.values()]
)
True
```

So, `df.rename(columns=selector_d)[selector_d.values()]` will suffice to select the new columns.

Comment: Hi pjdrew, it would add to your answer if you could explain the syntax, including the programming operations underlying the selecting part (`[[*selector_d.values()]`]. For instance, why do you need to use an asterix? Why can we not use just `[selector_d.values()]`?

Comment: @Hedge92 - you're right.  I was so used to having to pass a list to the pandas indexing operator `[]` that I started with the double brackets and worked out from there.  The unpack operator `*` was needed to unpack `selector_d.values()` into that inner list, but the inner list wasn't needed in the first place.  I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, there is a mistake in the first code block. The dict should read `{'Commander': 'Com', 'Score': 'sco'}`. The dict is correct in the second code block.

Comment: @user7868 - good catch, now fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`df.rename(columns = {"presentColumnName" : "NametoWhichYouWantTOChangeTo", "presentColumnName":"NametoWhichYouWantTOChangeTo"}, inplace=True)`

for your example

> `df.rename(columns = {"Com" : "Commander", "Sco":"Score"}, inplace=True)`

Comment: Thanks! One more thing is possible to add range of columns to select ? I mean `df.rename(columns = {"Com" : "Commander", Date:"Sco":Score"}, inplace=True)`

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what you mean. That is very vague.

Also if the above worked please accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.columns = ['Com', 'Date', 'Sco']
```

Comment: @Darek Langley it does not work when you want to select only Com and Sco!!

Comment: You can use a couple of conditionals to change that. For example you can do ls = df.columns. ls[ls=='Commander] = 'Com' or something along those lines.

Comment: So you are saying that there is no similar solution like R's select approach ? One line of code !

Comment: I am sure there is...I just don't know what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the same way in python as you did in R, using [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.all import tibble, select, f
>>> 
>>> data = {'Commander': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
...         'Date': ['2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08'], 
...         'Score': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
>>> 
>>> df = tibble(**data)
>>> df >> select(Com=f.Commander,Sco=f.Score)
       Com     Sco
  <object> <int64>
0    Jason       4
1    Molly      24
2     Tina      31
3     Jake       2
4      Amy       3
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.